# Defining commands in imported subfiles

Tags: standalone

I'm using the `standalone` package to create a document. The main document is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\import{Sections/}{Section1}
\section{Section 2}
\import{Sections/}{Section2}
\end{document}
```

Now within the `.tex` files `Section1` and `Section2` I have defined a new command

```
\newcommand{\br}{\mathbb{R}}
```

Which is required by both for standalone compilation, however when I try to compile `main.tex` this produces the error `Command \br already defined.` What is the best way for me to include new commands so that everything compiles correctly?

Comment: Define the command conditionally in each subfile and then define it in your main file. Or use `\providecommand...` rather than `\newcommand...`.

Comment: Or use subpreabbles=true on only the first file.